# Printing { and } with new format syntax

Tags: python

I need to add '{' and/or '}' in a string where I use the format function to format the string.  For example: I want my string to be "{3}", but this:

```
"\{{}\}".format(3)
```

gives me the error:

```
ValueError: Single '}' encountered in format string
```

Does anyone know how use '{' and '}' in string formatting?

Thanks,
Jeremy

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Simply duplicate the braces:

```
>>> "{{{0}}}".format(3)
'{3}'
```

Answer (score 6):

```
print "{{{0}}}".format(3)
'{3}'
```

Answer (score 6):

If you need unmatched brackets you could use something like:

```
>>> " {c}{x}{o}{o}".format(o='{',c='}', x=3)
' }3{{'
```

The doubling works for unmatched braces as well:

```
>>> "}} {} {{ {{".format(3)
'} 3  { {'
```