# how to get around "Single '}' encountered in format string" when using .format and formatting in printing

Tags: python

I am currently trying to print a tabulated format (using left alignment and padding) for headings in a table however I keep getting the following error.

```
ValueError: Single '}' encountered in format string
```

Here's the line:

```
print("{0}:<15}{1}:<15}{2}:<8}".format("1", "2", "3"))
```

Required output is something along the lines of:

```
1              2              3
```

I've tried duplicating the { } as advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374492/printing-and-with-new-format-syntax) but received no luck.

I am probably missing something incredibly obvious however after staring at it for ages, I cannot see it. After all, what's the harm in asking?

Thanks

Comment: There must be some extra `}` in code string

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Works:

```
>>> print("{0}:<15}}{1}:<15}}{2}:<8}}".format("1", "2", "3"))
1:<15}2:<15}3:<8}
```

**Edit:** Now I understand you. Do this:

```
print("{0:<15}{1:<15}{2:<8}".format("1", "2", "3"))
```

Details: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/

Comment: While that doesn't fail, I am looking for something that outputs something like the output I have edited into the post above. Apologies for not adding it earlier. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you describe in more detail the rquired output? Do you want tabs or should the "numbers" be aligned?

Comment: Sure. I've only just started learning python in the past few months so we are only doing the simple stuff. In this I am trying to use left alignment and padding. For example, first column has a padding of 15. then the second column starts with a padding of 15 again. Same for third with a padding of 8. Does this make it any clearer?

Comment: Ah. I see exactly what I've done wrong now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 26):

Use `}}`:

```
>>> "{0}:<15}}{1}:<15}}{2}:<8}}".format("1", "2", "3")
'1:<15}2:<15}3:<8}'
```

Comment: While that doesn't fail, I am looking for something that outputs something like the output I have edited into the post above. Apologies for not adding it earlier. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

The `{` and `}` characters need to be escaped where they're not part of the formatting template.

Try: `print("{0}:<15}}{1}:<15}}{2}:<8}}".format("1", "2", "3"))`

Outputs: `1:<15}2:<15}3:<8}`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Variables to do that. lenmax =  the max number of space needed, and op = the var i want to format with (both vars need to be set first)

```
print(('{:>' + str(lenmax) + '}').format(op), end='\t\t')
```

Things to remember:

- Parenthesis can be used.
- you can't concat ints so the var on the string must be transformed.
- the end statement gives you Tab so you don't have linejumps

hope works for someone.