# Python Regex - How to replace each character in a match with the same character (without function)

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to dynamically read regex matching rules and replacement rules from a txt file and send to re.sub function as parameters.

My input is `"PERSONALDETAILS TESTY MCTESTER 123 TEST DRIVE..."` - The length of data I need to replace is constant (100)

My output should be `"PERSONALDETAILS *****************************..."`

A sample file I have is as below:

```
"rules": 
{
        "(?<=PERSONALDETAILS).{1,100}": "####################################################################################################"
}
```

The replacement value I have above is hardcoded to 100 characters. Is there an elegant way to do this without using lambda function?

Comment: ...where is the lambda function?

Comment: *"The length of data I need to replace is constant"* - Use a regular plain old string replace, there is no point in using regex when the target substring is not variable.

Comment: Do you want to replace anything that starts with `PERSONALDETAILS ` and the rest of it minus the last 3 chars as `*` ?

Comment: No elegant way exists then, you may only "unwrap" the pattern into alternations like `(?<=PERSONALDETAILS.{99}).|(?<=PERSONALDETAILS.{98}).|..repeat 97 times..|(?<=PERSONALDETAILS).` and replace with `#`.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your rules and read them as json data type;

1. Reserve your rules.
2. Make placeholder for target length of your rules instead of hardcoded n characters. You can do this job by using **{}** and **.format()** property, like this:

   `(?<=PERSONALDETAILS).{{{start}, {end}}}`
3. Save your rules as a json file.
4. Read your rules as a json file.
5. Iterating rules (keys and values) and replace their values.

**Try this:**

```
import re
text = "PERSONALDETAILS TESTY MCTESTER 123 TEST DRIVE..."
rules = {"(?<=PERSONALDETAILS).{{{start},{end}}}": "####################################################################################################"}

for each_pattern, each_replacement in rules.items():
    text = re.sub(each_pattern.format(start=1, end=100), each_replacement, text)

print(text)
```

**Reading your rules from json file:**

```
import json 

with open("rules.json") as json_file:
    rules = json.load(json_file)["rules"]
```

**Full Code:**

```
import re
from json import load, dump


rules = {
    "(?<=PERSONALDETAILS_1).{{{start},{end}}}": "#####################################################",
    "(?<=PERSONALDETAILS_2).{{{start},{end}}}": "*****************************************************",
    "(?<=PERSONALDETAILS_3).{{{start},{end}}}": "=====================================================",
}

with open('rules.json', 'w') as json_file:
    dump(rules, json_file)

with open("rules.json") as json_file:
    rules = load(json_file)["rules"]


target_text = "PERSONALDETAILS TESTY MCTESTER 123 TEST DRIVE..."
for each_pattern, each_replacement in rules.items():
    text = re.sub(each_pattern.format(start=1, end=100), each_replacement, target_text)

print(target_text)
```

Some credits to this question [how to get around "Single '}' encountered in format string" when using .format and formatting in printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079540/how-to-get-around-single-encountered-in-format-string-when-using-format-a) and [@fred-fro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166749/fred-foo)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do? If so, you may not need a regex.

```
txt = '''PERSONALDETAILS TESTY MCTESTER 123 TEST DRIVE...
PERSONALDETAILS THIS IS THE SECOND LINE IN THE TXT FILE...
PERSONALDETAILS THIS IS THE THIRD LINE IN THE SAMPLE TXT FILE...
PERSONALDETAILS THE FOURTH LINE IN TXT FILE...
THIS LINE DOES NOT STARTWITH PERSONALDETAILS...
PERSONAL DETAILS THIS LINE STARTS BUT HAS A SAPCE INBETWEEN...
PERSONALDETAILS LINE SEVEN OF TXT FILE...'''

replaced_txt = ''
print (txt)

for x in txt.split('\n'):
    if x.startswith('PERSONALDETAILS'):
        replaced_txt += ''.join([x[:16],'*' * (len(x) - 18),x[-3:],'\n'])
    else:
        replaced_txt += x + '\n'

print (replaced_txt)
```

The output of this will be:

Original file:

```
PERSONALDETAILS TESTY MCTESTER 123 TEST DRIVE...
PERSONALDETAILS THIS IS THE SECOND LINE IN THE TXT FILE...
PERSONALDETAILS THIS IS THE THIRD LINE IN THE SAMPLE TXT FILE...
PERSONALDETAILS THE FOURTH LINE IN TXT FILE...
THIS LINE DOES NOT STARTWITH PERSONALDETAILS...
PERSONAL DETAILS THIS LINE STARTS BUT HAS A SAPCE INBETWEEN...
PERSONALDETAILS LINE SEVEN OF TXT FILE...
```

Modified file:

```
PERSONALDETAILS ******************************...
PERSONALDETAILS ****************************************...
PERSONALDETAILS **********************************************...
PERSONALDETAILS ****************************...
THIS LINE DOES NOT STARTWITH PERSONALDETAILS...
PERSONAL DETAILS THIS LINE STARTS BUT HAS A SAPCE INBETWEEN...
PERSONALDETAILS ***********************...
```